# I want to make a grid and a rectangle shape inside the grid

Tags: graphics, diagrams

Hi everyone I am trying to draw in latex but it is hard. I want to make a grid and a rectangle shape inside the grid with few labels. I would really appreciate some help!!
[image]

Comment: Welcome! What have you got so far? Questions should generally include the code you've got so that we can better understand what you're having trouble with. Do-it-for-me questions sometimes get answered, sometimes not. But answers may not be very useful to you, and people are less inclined to answer depending on whether your question is a sufficiently intriguing/challenging/appealing/attractive/etc. one.

Comment: I am sorry, I totally would but I do not know how to even make the grid of dots. The hardest picture I have made so far was a complete graph of 6 vertices, but this much harder for me. I apologize I am not sure where to start.

Comment: You can always post the 6 - then people know you have the basics and, also, they don't have to construct a new document from scratch. Also, knowing how you do the 6 makes it possible to build on that approach e.g. using the same package for drawing or whatever, which is usually easier and more helpful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For example, the points of the grid can be set as empty circle nodes. Then the connecting lines will connect to the circle leaving the inner of the circle intact. The grid can be drawn via nested `\foreach` loop for the two dimensions:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \foreach \x in {0, ..., 5} {
    \foreach \y in {0, ..., 3} {
      \node[
        circle,
        minimum size=3pt,
        draw,
        inner sep=0pt,
      ] (n\x_\y) at (\x, \y) {};
    }
  }
  \draw
    (n0_0) -- (n1_0) -- (n2_0) -- (n3_0) -- (n4_0) -- (n5_0)
    (n0_0) -- (n3_1)
    (n1_0) -- (n3_1)
    (n2_0) -- (n3_1)
    (n3_0) -- (n3_1)
    (n4_0) -- (n3_1)
    (n4_0) -- (n4_1)
    (n5_0) -- (n4_1)
    (n5_0) -- (n5_1)
    (n3_1) -- (n4_1) -- (n5_1)
  ;
  \node[below] at (n0_0) {$(0, 0)$};
  \node[above] at (n3_1) {$(a, 1)$};
  \node[above right] at (n5_1) {$(a + b, 1)$};
  \node[left=1ex] at (n0_3) {$v$};
  \node[below=1ex] at (n5_0) {$t$};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

> [image: Result]

Answer (score 0):

Her is a short code with `pstricks`. You can compile with `pdflatex` if the switch `--enable-write18` (MiKTeX) or `-shell-escape` (TeX Live, MacTeX) is set:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,11pt,x11names]{article}
\usepackage{pst-node, multido}
\usepackage{auto-pst-pdf}

\begin{document}%

\psset{xunit =1.5, nodesep=2pt, linecolor=IndianRed3}
\footnotesize
\begin{pspicture}
    \multido{\Ix=0 + 1}{6}{\multido{\Iy=0 + 1}{4}{\dotnode(\Ix, \Iy){A\Ix\Iy}}}
    \multido{\Ix=0 + 1}{5}{\ncline{A\Ix0}{A31}}
    \multido{\I=0 + 1, \In=1 + 1}{5} {\ncline{A\I0}{A\In0}}
    \ncline{A31}{A40}
    \ncline{A41}{A31}\ncline{A41}{A51}\ncline{A41}{A40}\ncline{A41}{A50}\ncline{A50}{A51}
    \uput[dl](A00){$ (0,0) $}\uput[dr](A50){$ t $}\uput[l](A03){$ V $}
    \uput[ur](A31){$ (a, 1) $}\uput[ur](A51){$ (a + b, 1) $}
\end{pspicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]